# Getting Seg Fault in C

Tags: c

So I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {

  char ch;

  printf("Enter Phone Number: ");
  ch = getchar();

  while (ch != '\n') {
    switch(ch) {
      case 'A':
      case 'B':
      case 'C':
        printf('2');
        break;
      case 'D':
      case 'E':
      case 'F':
        printf('3');
        break;
      case 'G':
      case 'H':
      case 'I':
        printf('4');
        break;
      case 'J':
      case 'K':
      case 'L':
        printf('5');
        break;
      case 'M':
      case 'N':
      case 'O':
        printf('6');
        break;
      case 'P':
      case 'R':
      case 'S':
        printf('7');
        break;
      case 'T':
      case 'U':
      case 'V':
        printf('8');
        break;
      case 'W':
      case 'X':
      case 'Y':
        printf('9');
        break;
      default:
        printf('%c', ch);
        break;
    }

    ch = getchar();
  }
}
```

And the goal is:

```
input: CALLATT
output: 2255288
```

or

```
input: 1-800-COL-LECT
output: 1-800-265-5328
```

When I run the program:

```
Enter Phone Number: CALLATT
Segmentation fault: 11
```

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" --> You did not fully enable the compilers warnings.  Properly enabled `printf('2');` would have generated a diagnostic and you would have corrected it straight away.  Saves you time.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -g -Wall` then use the `gdb` debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using single quotes to delimit strings passed to `printf`.  You need to use double quotes.

So change this:

```
printf('%c', ch);
```

To this:

```
printf("%c", (char)ch);
```

And similarly in other calls to `printf`.

Also, you need to declare `ch` as `int` in order to detect an EOF condition:

```
while ((ch != EOF) && (ch != '\n') {
```

Comment: Maybe it's just really really obfuscated code.  JK!

Comment: ... and buy a real compiler. They're free, so you should be able to afford one. :)

Comment: @unwind I highly doubt he is not using gcc as he is newbie and programming on linux. And gcc is considered a real compiler

Comment: I am on mac, a newbie and yes I am using GCC.

Comment: @TheWebs And did you not get any compiler errors for that quoting error? That's my point, GCC will error out on this, it's not correct code so it can't compile. Or at least it should warn, although I think it's bad enough to be an error.

Comment: @unwind For me, gcc throws up a warning:  "warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: @dbush Hm, okay, too bad. I tried it on ideone.com, but I guess they set it to error on warnings too.

Answer (score -1):

Four things:

1. Use `putchar` instead of `printf`.
2. Declare `ch` as `int`.
3. In the `while`-loop, put the condition `ch = getchar () != EOF`.
4. Remove `ch = getchar();` from the end of the `while`-loop.

Comment: Please read about [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and text and code [formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). It will help improve quality and readability of your answers. Thanks..